# beta distribution on arbitrary interval

Tags: random-variable, simulation

Given that I can simulate $X \sim Beta(a,b)$ on $(0,1)$, how can I simulate $Y \sim GBeta(a,b)$ (generalized beta) on $(p, q)$ for arbitrary $p, q \in \mathbb{R}$? Is it just $Y = (p-q) X + p$

Comment: FYI "generalized beta" name is also taken https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_beta_distribution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [non-standard beta distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/186465/difference-between-standard-beta-and-unstandard-beta-distributions/186467#186467). Simply take

$$
Y = X \times (q - p) + p
$$